# JavaFX - How to apply PrefixSelectionComboBox to ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I'd like to add a listener to a ComboBox which filters out results in the list not matching the user input. I.e. if the list contains [ "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "cba", "abc" ] and the user enters 'b', the items left would be 'bbb', 'cba', 'abc'.

I understand that the PrefixSelectionComboBox is what I'm looking for but I can't get it to work. I press the combobox and press keys but it doesn't react. The ComboBox-relevant code is:

```
@FXML
private ComboBox<Student> studentComboBox;
@FXML
private ComboBox<Course> courseComboBox;

@FXML
private void initialize() {

    studentComboBox.getItems().addAll(DALStudent.findAllStudents());
    courseComboBox.getItems().addAll(DALCourse.findAllCourses());

    PrefixSelectionCustomizer.customize(studentComboBox);
    PrefixSelectionCustomizer.customize(courseComboBox);
}

// rest of code
```

where the ComboBoxes are assigned to a corresponding ComboBox in the GUI/SceneBuilder. I've also tried using the PrefixSelectionComboBox in SceneBuilder, and I have read the post at http://www.kware.net/?p=233#Using_it but it simply refers to using the customize method.

Do I need to do something differently?

Comment: I think PrefixSelectionCustomizer is only for matching text to put in combobox not for filtering ComboBox list.

Comment: The feature that PrefixSelectionCustomizer enables is: The user can press a squence of keys on the keyboard an the approriate value will be selected by the combo box. No filtering. If you did want to filter you can use a FilteredList to populate the combo box and then set the predicate whenever you get new input.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @christoph.keimel, I'll look into the FilteredList instead